# Java - Copy pixels of BufferedImage to list

Tags: java, image

I made a bitmap class with a list of Pixels. The Pixel class has a position and a color. Now I am trying to get a bitmap from a BufferedImage.

This is the code I have tried:

```
    private static Bitmap fromImage(BufferedImage image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();
        for (int x = image.getMinX(); x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = image.getMinY(); y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                bitmap.setPixel(new Pixel(RGBAColor.fromColor(
                        new Color(image.getRGB(x, y))), new Vector2(x, y)));
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    public static Bitmap fromImage(String path) {
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(Galaxy2D.class.getResource(
                    "/com/mcmastery/galaxy2d/resources/" + path));
            BufferedImage conImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            conImg.createGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            return Bitmap.fromImage(conImg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It works, but when it paints the image to the screen it distorts it.
Original image: http://gyazo.com/0832ebf26f940b6dbf218e43101e63f8.png
Image painted to screen using bitmap methods: http://gyazo.com/c4b776f0e5fa0e54c167c10947582834.png

I have tried DataBufferInt too, and it still produces the same result. With other images, it just changes some pixel's positions to positions close to where they are supposed to be. But with the crosshair above, it turns it black and distorts it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a Bitmap is used for (I can't find it in the JDK7 API).

Maybe you can just use the `getSubImage(...)` method of the `BufferedImage`.

Comment: I said I made my own bitmap class.

Comment: I am making a little game engine and I want to basically kind of rewrite all the java classes that are used, so games using the engine only use imports from the engine. I want to copy all the pixels from an image to a list of pixels inside my bitmap class.

Comment: Then I see no reason why you can't use the getSubImage() method and just deal with a complete image for the game. I don't know why you care about the individual pixels.

Comment: So I can copy them to a list. I don't want to use the default image class.